# jQuery preventDefault() not working with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, refresh

Yes, I have read through many other posts with the same problem, but I'm not understanding how to fix this. I created a bookmarking button, and it needs to change icons on click.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    
    var bm = jQuery(".user_bookmark");
    
    bm.on("click", ".user_bookmark", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id")
        nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")

        jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : bookmarkAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "eri_user_bookmark", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                var add = 'Add Bookmark';
                var remove = 'Remove Bookmark';
                var display = bm.attr('display');
                var bookmarked = bm.attr('bookmarked');
                if (display == 'icon') {
                    add = '<i class="x-icon" data-x-icon-o="&#xf02e;" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                    remove = '<i class="x-icon" data-x-icon-s="&#xf02e;" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                }
                if (bookmarked) {
                    bm.html(remove);
                    bm.attr('bookmarked', 'false');
                } else {
                    bm.html(add);
                    bm.attr('bookmarked', 'true');
                }
            }
            else {
               alert("Your bookmark could not be added")
            }
         }
        })  
    });

})
```

First I had `bm.click()`, but it was only working with one click, then I read to switch to the `.on()` function, and now it's refreshing the page.

I tried switching out `function (e)` with `function ()` and replacing `e.preventDefault();` with `return false;`, `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, and `e.stopPropagation();`.

Also tried switching `bm.on()` with `jQuery(document).on()` with all of these variations. That still ran my code and did not refresh, but it's not changing the elements from the jQuery code.

Example HTML:

```
<a class="user_bookmark" data-nonce="2b92b05de9" data-post_id="1" href="https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=eri_user_bookmark&amp;post_id=1&amp;nonce=2b92b05de9" display="icon" bookmarked="true" style="outline: none;">
   <i class="x-icon" data-x-icon-s="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Full PHP Gist: https://gist.github.com/mrgandy/91361fca86e769235eec684a4647b875

Comment: Do you have nested `.user_bookmark` elements? If not, then the issue is to do with how you're attaching the event handler, not `preventDefault`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I'm not sure what you mean. I added my full code above if you wouldn't mind taking a quick look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're accidentally nesting the event handler. You're attaching a delegated event handler to `.user_bookmark` which is listening for click events on *child* `.user_bookmark` elements. Your HTML shows these elements are not nested, hence the event handler never fires so neither `preventDefault()`, or your AJAX request, is called.

Assuming the `<a />` elements you're trying to target are not dynamically created, then remove the second argument you're using in the `on()` call.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $bm = $('.user_bookmark');

  $bm.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
    let nonce = $(this).data('nonce');

    console.log(post_id, nonce);
    console.log('ajax request here...');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="user_bookmark" data-nonce="2b92b05de9" data-post_id="1" href="https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=eri_user_bookmark&amp;post_id=1&amp;nonce=2b92b05de9" display="icon" bookmarked="true" style="outline: none;">
  <i class="x-icon" data-x-icon-s="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  Lorem ipsum
</a>
```

If the elements are in fact dynamically added to the DOM after the page loads, then you need to assign the delegated event handler to a static parent, which would look something like this:

```
jQuery($ => {
  $(document).on('click', '.user_bookmark', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let post_id = $(this).data("post_id");
    let nonce = $(this).data("nonce");

    console.log(post_id, nonce);
    console.log('ajax request here...');
  });
})
```